# how to set an Ip address to virtualhost using xampp and directing devices through LAN

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I've developed a wordpress website on my local pc using xampp
i want to create a virtual host for it and let other pc's on my Lan to see the website using nameserver.
my apache code is like this

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.122:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
 <Directory  "C:\xampp\htdocs\SiteName">
    Require ip 192.168.2.122
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
   ServerName localhost
```

and

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.122:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\SiteName"
<Directory  "C:\xampp\htdocs\SiteName"> 
    Require ip 192.168.2.122
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ServerName test.asi
```

my local pc Ip in network is 192.168.2.122
when other devices use my nameserver on their browser, they see THEIR localhost files not the one i have on my computer

Comment: How you are accessing you host from other computers can you provide a complete url

Comment: i have a local network
using wifi connection and a router

Comment: I asked you what the url you are hitting from another computers

Comment: no you can't do this without modification of your host file or you need to configure you own DNS server

Comment: is server accessible from ip address ?

Comment: and remove `Require ip` is will make your host inaccessible from another computers